# Sigma laws problem / sigma distribution

Tags: calculus, probability

][1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/u9uxw.png)

Hi 
Can somebody explain to me how that was made using sigma laws . 
Thank you for help in advance

Answer (score 1):

Well this is easy! Rewrite the sum as
$$\sum_{k=1}^{n}n-k=\sum_{k=1}^n n-\sum_{k=1}^{n}k=n^2-\frac{n(n+1)}{2}=n^2-\frac{n^2(1+\tfrac{1}{n})}{2}=n^2\Big(\frac{2-1-\tfrac{1}{n}}{2}\Big)=n^2\Big(\frac{1-\tfrac{1}{n}}{2}\Big)$$
No sigma laws were used here!

**Edit:**
$$\sum_{k=1}^n n=\underbrace{n+\cdots+n}_{n\text{ times}}=n^2$$

Comment: ok so how do you solve the first sum ∑n . Do you just multiply by n ?

Comment: $$\sum_{k=1}^n n=n\sum_{k=1}^n 1=n\underbrace{(1+\cdots+1)}_{\text{n times}}=n^2$$

Comment: @PhilipMichalowski $$\sum\limits_{k=1}^n n=\underbrace{n+n+...+n}_{\textrm{n-times}}=n\cdot n$$

Comment: @JohnDoe oh ok , thank you very much